# Removing 300ms tap delay on mobile web.

Tags: ios, mobile, gesture, hammer.js, iphone-web-app

I am trying to have an element respond to a tap on a mobile device. Tapping the black box should reveal elements behind the top div. See here: http://shaloon.com/help/

When I implement hammer.js "tap" in lieu of jQuery's "click", my interaction doesn't work.

**This works:**

```
$('.HomeButton').on("click", function() {  
   $(".FeedContainer").toggleClass("FeedContainerDOWN");
});
```

**This doesn't work**

```
$('.HomeButton').hammer().bind("tap", function() {  
   $(".FeedContainer").toggleClass("FeedContainerDOWN");
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**FastClick.js** removes the 300ms delay for Tap on mobile devices

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Include the javascript file and then use this code for attaching it to the body:

```
FastClick.attach(document.body);
```